# Can "during" be always substituted with "in"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> He kissed her during a drunken night.
>
> He kissed her in a drunken night.

Can "during" be always substituted with "in"? I am always wondering about it, because I use *during* as a synonym for *in*. Is it correct to do so?

Comment: **during** means **in a period of time**, and in this example is better replaced by **on a drunken night**, **on a sunny afternoon**, but **in the nighttime**.  You can use **in** in many other ways, including target: **in the face**, location: **in the park**, mental state: **in excitement**, speed: **in the blink of any eye**.

Comment: Apparently things like "I am in the class". "I'm in the toilet" can not swappable by "during". It came a bit as a shock to me a native English speakers uses these terms **in** such a way.

Answer (score 1):

No, *in* cannot always be substituted for *during*:

> I fainted **during** the movie.

→ I fainted while watching the movie.

> I fainted **in** the movie.

→ I acted in the movie, and the character I played fainted in a particular scene.

---

Note that context determines the meaning.

If you've clearly established that you were in the audience *watching* a movie, then using the word *in* would result in something nonsensical—only *during* would be appropriate in that context.